# Сборка библиотек при помощи MinGW и MSYS2, настройка ./Configure

Tags: компиляция, mingw, кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь собрать PortAudio - не находит компилятор, который есть в Path и успешно собрал не один десяток проектов и либ:
[image: no_compiler]

**Как вручную прописывать пути к компиляторам в Configure, если оно не видит их `$PATH`?**

Компилятор видно через cmd:
[image: gccv]

Comment: А компилятор точно есть? Что выводит `gcc -v`?

Comment: @zed, вывод cmd прикрепил

Comment: что в config.log? И на будущее, прикрепляй текст, а не скриншоты...

Comment: Попробуйте не в msys2 консоль заходить, а в mingw32 или mingw64 (если собираете 64-х битное приложение). И уже в той консоли проверяйте доступность gcc.

Comment: @zed, может оно пытается использовать 64 бинтую версию компилятора, которая у меня не установлена (в MSYS2\mingw64 пусто, ставил только mingw32)? Если да, какой командой указать целевую платформу/компилятор?

Comment: Не должно. В этом и смысл разных консолей, что они настроены на работу с конкретным компилятором. А PATH они вообще игнорируют по дефолту. Попробуйте переустановить согласно вот [этой инструкции](https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2). Главное, делайте всё один-в-один как там расписано (вплоть до пути и имени папки установки), раз уж вы не можете найти у себя проблему при самостоятельной установке. Единственное, можно опустить п.6 (не прописывать путь к компиляторам в PATH). У меня при установке по этой инструкции никаких проблем не возникало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что после какого-то из апдейтов MSYS2 он по умолчанию перестал наследовать прописанный в системе PATH.

Чтобы это исправить, нужно в корне MSYS2 изменить файл `msys2_shell.cmd` - в нём нужно раскомментировать строку `set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit`, удалив перед ней команду `rem`. Естественно в PATH должен быть путь к компилятору, и консоль MSYS нужно перезапустить после этих манипуляций.